# wordpress search query error

Tags: php, wordpress, search, authentication

I make a metabox that make a post Private or Public.

When user is login all posts will be shown but when user not login only public posts will be shown.

Everything is okay my query and condition working well in other pages, but when I search a post and I am logout the private posts also be showed to me.

I could not understand what happen. Here is my code:

**search.php**

```
<?php
    global $post;

    $public = array('meta_key' => 'rd_login_posts', 'meta_value' => 0, 'posts_per_page' => 999);
    $public_private = array('posts_per_page' => 999);

    if(!is_user_logged_in()){
        $st_cat_posts = get_posts($public);
        //echo "No Login";
    }else{
        $st_cat_posts = get_posts($public_private);
        //echo "Yes Login";
    }

    foreach($st_cat_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
             get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
    endforeach; 
?>
```

In two pages it works fine but in searching, the result is not perfect it shows me all results.

Please help me, any suggestions

Comment: Have you added this code into `search.php` ???

Comment: yes i add this code in search.php after this <?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'framework' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot @Akshay Paghdar for helping me, but i search ,search and found a solution and my code is running well

search.php i only edit one more parameter in arrays

```
$public = array('meta_key' => 'rd_login_posts', 'meta_value' => 0, 'posts_per_page' => 999, 's' => get_search_query());
$public_private = array('posts_per_page' => 999, 's' => get_search_query());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

You should add this code in your `search.php`..

```
<?php 
global $post;

if(!is_user_logged_in()){
    set_query_var('meta_key', 'rd_login_posts');
    set_query_var('meta_value', 0);
}
set_query_var('posts_per_page', 999);

if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Hope it works...

Comment: set_query_var() when i write this my editor gives me syntax error

Comment: no bro, when i logout the private also shown - private posts hide when user logout only public posts shown

Comment: Have you check my above code in your system ????Coz i have added condition `if(!is_user_logged_in()){` check that...

Comment: sorry in my question i dont need this $st_sub_category_id in search sorry once again

Comment: how can i write my own search query is this possible in WP